# How can I navigate between screens in React Native without using navigation.navigate()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

As you may see from the title, my question is if there's a way to navigate between screens without using navigation.navigate(). If you are gonna use navigation.navigate(), the screen has to be defined in your navigation stack, but if I wanna navigate to a screen that's not defined in the navigation stack, how can I achieve that?

Comment: Check this out - https://github.com/saminadhikari/react-native-chat-starter/blob/master/App.js. You would mainly wanna use it for authentication flow but can use it for anything or any component

Comment: Also see this - https://github.com/saminadhikari/react-native-chat-starter/blob/master/src/screens/login/Login.js. The key here is to understand "Context";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use useNavigation hook from any component;
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/connecting-navigation-prop

Comment: Isn't this only for screen names defined in the Navigation Stack?